# Deleting lines upward in vim Linux

Tags: linux, vim

How to do that in vim, lets say im in line 100 and i want to delete 20 lines upward? how to do that in vim linux?

Comment: Try vimtutor, its the best 30mins you'll ever use, if you plan to use vim.

Comment: where can i find that 30 min vimtutor thingy?

Comment: Just run the command vimtutor, it will bring up a vim-instance with a tutorial.

Comment: `$ vimtutor` on *nix, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\vimtutor.bat` on Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In normal mode you can use `d` and the movenment key `k` to delete upwards. And then you prefix that command with the number of times you want to repeat the command like `100dk`.

If you just want to delete to the beginning you can use `gg` along with `d`, `gg` sends the cursor to the first character in the file. So `ggd` will delete the first line to the line you are standing on.

Comment: are you sure its 100dk or d100k? cause i tried d100k it do the work. are there any difference?

Comment: @Shahbaz, have you actually tried it in vim? `d5k` says 6 fewer lines and `5dk` says 6 fewer lines.

Comment: @jbr, I was mistaken. I had tried and it seemed to me that `2dk` removed 4 lines (but apparently I miscounted). Anyway, you are right, even though I would have expected `5dk` to do `dk` five times, removing ten lines.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it relative if you know the number of lines:

```
d20k
```

Or absolute if you know the line number:

```
d80G
```

`d` = delete, `20k` = 20 lines up, `80G` = goto line 80

Or without taking you current position into account:

```
:80,100d
```

Personally, I use [visual mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html) a lot becuase it gives me a nice feedback:

- hit <kbd>V</kbd> to enter visual line mode
- move 20 lines up with <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>
- adjust selection with <kbd>k</kbd> and <kbd>j</kbd> if necessary
- press <kbd>d</kbd> to delete selection

Comment: I suggest starting out with the visual mode too and as @Stefan said you can adjust your selection with regular movements; `o` comes handy here to move between the ends of that selection.

Comment: +1 for use of visual line. It's just as efficient, and easier to not miss/stop and think.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it upwards with the range.

```
:-20,.d
```

In this you can specify the range of line to delete it .

Will deletes 20 lines upwards to the  current and this is kind of  an ex-mode command.